# How to parse objects from JSON in JavaScript and avoid [Function (anonymous)]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I have a JSON file, that contains an object "books":

```
{
    "books": {
        "book1": {
            "name": "Smth1",
            "about": "Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>",
            "file": "id",
            "fileDesc": "Текст к файлу"
        },
        "book2": {
            "name": "Smth2",
            "about": "Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>",
            "file": "id",
            "fileDesc": "Текст к файлу"
        }
    }
}
```

And I need this object. But when I read an object from file and print it:

```
const obj = require('./file.json').books
console.log(obj)
```

I get:

```
  book1: {
    name: [Function (anonymous)],
    about: [Function (anonymous)],
    file: [Function (anonymous)],
    fileDesc: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  book2: {
    name: [Function (anonymous)],
    about: [Function (anonymous)],
    file: [Function (anonymous)],
    fileDesc: [Function (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

And can't work with object. How can I fix it?

Comment: this json file doesnt look like valid syntax tbh. No top level brackts.

Comment: Please check the balancing of braces, and depict JSON as valid JSON. JSON cannot start with `"books":`, in case of an object it should start with `{`. But more importantly, what do you mean with "And can't work with object"? If you were able to output it with `console.log`, you have a valid object. So what's the problem?

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for your advises. As I wrote, this is just an object from JSON file, nut full file

Comment: You realize that console.log output is way different than JSON.stringify

Comment: Your parser is doing something weird, JSON can't even store functions.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a proper json

```
{
    "books": {
        "book1": {
            "name": "Smth1",
            "about": "Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>",
            "file": "id",
            "fileDesc": "Текст к файлу"
        },
        "book2": {
            "name": "Smth2",
            "about": "Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>",
            "file": "id",
            "fileDesc": "Текст к файлу"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can read it

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('books.json', 'utf8'));
```

Output from Node terminal

```
> obj
{
  books: {
    book1: {
      name: 'Smth1',
      about: 'Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>',
      file: 'id',
      fileDesc: 'Текст к файлу'
    },
    book2: {
      name: 'Smth2',
      about: 'Тут <b>описание</b> <i>книги</i>',
      file: 'id',
      fileDesc: 'Текст к файлу'
    }
  }
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

only in file.js add curly braces:

```
{
    "books": {
        // ..
    }
}
```